# Помогите с onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Есть авторизация в приложении с помощью VK SDK, щас надо сделать авторизацию с помощью GoogleSignInApi....Тоесть у меня после авторизации запускается лента новостей, при авторизации с вк проблем нет(он свой токен получил и запустил ленту), а вот в GoogleSignInApi получает свой токен, а нодо то и свой и токен от вк.....вот я и не понимаю как это реализовать

```
      public void onClickLoginVK(View view) {
                VKSdk.login(this, scopes);
            }


            public void onClickLoginGL(View view) {
                signIn();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                    handleSignInResult(result);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VKError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
    private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

            if (result.isSuccess()) {

                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

                String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                String email = acct.getEmail();

                txtex.setText(personName);

Ion.with(im).error(R.drawable.ic_about).animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE).load(personPhotoUrl);

                } else {

                }
            }}
```

Как нить можно отловить токен с вк при авторизации с GoogleSignInApi ???

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не понятен, но надо так:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: добрый день.Юрий можно ли как то получить точки дорог между 2 точками на карте .Допустим чтоб не пользоваться Directions api.Мне как то надо получить пути между 2 точками.Не моглиб помоч

Comment: @elik, я в этой области не силён. Не думаю, что есть разумный способ это сделать без использования сторонних АПИ

Comment: наешл альтернативу но придется использовать openstreetmap

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при авторизации с GoogleSignInApi открывалась лента с ВК, но не получается отловить токен с вк и авторизация не проходит.

Comment: @sviter-pro, вы же понимаете, что залогинившись через гугл вы не получите токен для ВК? Что для полчения токена ВК надо в ВК логиниться? Или вам надо после логина в ВК залогиниться в гугл и после логина в гугл получить токен залогинненного в ВК юзера?

Comment: у меня в приложении есть лента новостей! но ее никак не прочитаешь, пока не залогинишься...С вк понятно что логиниться....а вот GoogleSignInApi проблема.... тоесть я хочу чтобы с GoogleSignInApi логмнилось так же как с вк!!! это Просто выбор пользователям с чего логиниться!

Comment: @sviter-pro, `я хочу чтобы с GoogleSignInApi логмнилось так же как с вк` - это очень расплывчато. Что именно должно быть `также`? Чего именно у вас с логином гугла не выходит по сравнению с ВК? У вас не выходит имя и аватарку получить или что? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Вот когда залогинился один раз через авторизацию из вк, то сразу открывается лента новостей... А когда через гугл, то ничего не происходит (типа открылось окно с моим пользователем) я на него тыкнул и больше ничего...

Comment: @sviter-pro, всё ещё не понятно что должно произойти. Открыться окно юзера? Т.е. у вас где-то какой-то метод не вызывается? Если да - то какой? Старайтесь так формулировать вопрос, чтобы выяснение вашей проблемы не занимало много часов

Comment: Исходя из того кода что показал я в вопросе, то у меня получается что после авторизации в вк открывается новое активити с recyclerview(получившее токен от вк) и все работает стабильно.....а в гугл тоже открывается активити с recyclerview, но лента не работает ибо токен то брать надо от вк, а как это сделать я незнаю....

Comment: @sviter-pro, я уже говорил выше, что это невозможно. У гугла нет токена ВК. Залогинившись через гугл вы получите только доступ к акку в гугле. ВК тут совсем-совсем никак вообще не прикрутить.

Comment: А через FaceBook как ниить можно? В веб версии есть FaceBook авторизация....

Comment: @sviter-pro, вы про вход в ВК через FaceBook? Если да, то я не знаю. Надо смотреть в АПИ. Скорее всего такой возможности нет